# Analytics Kit - When Response Content From Connection inputStream operation exception! 40

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I'm trying to implement Huawei Analytics Kit in the app, but unfortunately I faced with a problem, when in debug mode my custom event's are not displaying on the web in App debugging. In logs I can see the following error, that is saying that I have no network or no Internet permission which is NOT true in my case.

```
W/HiAnalyticsSDK: HttpClient=> When Response Content From Connection inputStream operation exception! 401
W/HiAnalyticsSDK: StreamUtil=> closeQuietly(): Exception when connHttp.getInputStream()!,There may be no network, or no INTERNET permission
I/HiAnalyticsSDK: ReportInstance=> response code : 401
I/HiAnalyticsSDK: SendTask=> events PostRequest sendevent TYPE : oper, TAG : _openness_config_tag, resultCode: 401 ,reqID:530a86a50e7643cb83ec1328b5332fbf
I/HiAnalyticsSDK: SendTask=> is debug mode
```

Could you suggest me please the source of this kind of problem, because I've already made a full research of documentation and didn't find the solution of this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Have you already set _signingConfigs_ for Debug mode in _build.gradle_?

Answer (score 0):

Would you mind provide some further info for further check?

-The version number for Huawei Analytics SDK
-Data storage area selected when analysis service is enabled
-A complete Huawei Analytics SDK log, from initialization to error occured

Answer (score 0):

Error code 401 means unauthorized access or invalid login credential. Please make sure that you have include your agconnect-services.json in your app directory, enable and configure Analytics API correctly in your developer console.

You can refer to this FAQ - https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides-V5/environment-faq-0000001050162062-V5.

Please go over this doc and make sure that you don’t miss any step - https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides-V5/android-dev-process-0000001050163813-V5.